# scanner expects two inputs

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a very simple java code that expects an integer with scanner.Int() and output some calculation based on the input.

The issue is , it only gives the outputs after my second input
although it ignores the first one.

For example:
Aftre running , i see cursor waiting,

I type 5 + ENTER

*cursor waiting*

I type 3 + ENTER

*output:* 45

(which is the result regarding the second input)

I'm running it on Intellij IDEA 2019.2

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(((n+1)*n+2)*n+3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code and it works as you want it to work, meaning, I can type `5` + Enter and get the result `163` straight away. IntelliJ 2019.1.4.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian so i guess it's something about my configuration, but what?

Comment: Are you sure the correct window has focus when you enter the first number? Can you see `5` printed out when you enter it?

Comment: I think i know , sort of, it's intellij with Edu tutorials plugins , i think it adds some configurations 
checked in "standard" intellij   - no issue

Answer (score -1):

It was caused by Intellij Edu edition, 
it added some configurations that mess with it (i think it's gradle)
checked the same code on standard intellij - no issue